# How does this not lead to multiple enumerations of an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

I originally set my parameter type to be ICollection because I thought I would run into issues with multiple enumerations of an IEnumerable.  However, Resharper suggested that I can convert the parameter type to be an IEnumerable.  I ended up making a test to double check and it seems to work fine:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var nums = GetNums();
        MultipleEnumerations(nums);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void MultipleEnumerations(IEnumerable<int> nums)
    {
        var otherNums = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        var filtered = otherNums.Where(num => nums.Contains(num));
        foreach (var num in filtered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> GetNums()
    {
        yield return 4;
        yield return 2;
    }
```

How does this not lead to multiple enumerations of an IEnumerable?

Comment: `otherNums` is a list.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it would lead to multiple enumerations? -- After trying it out you're right: without materializing the array you're going to be doing multiple enumerations. Perhaps it's just a scenario R# can't detect well.

Comment: In order to determine if the number from the otherNums list is in the nums IEnumerable, it would have to iterate over all of the elements in nums.  Since we're doing this check for each int in otherNums, I would figure that this would be multiple enumerations.

Comment: I guess Resharper just isn't capable of detecting that your `Where` clause will be run multiple times

Comment: It's not just that resharper thinks that the code is fine. It actually run with no problems.  I was wondering how.

Comment: because you already have a materialized list.  there is not deferred execution of the list which would lead to the underlying data changing between traversals.

Comment: That the code runs with no problem doesn't mean there isn't multiple enumeration. http://ideone.com/OhMmOY

Comment: I see. I did not realize that you could enumerate multiple times over an IEnumerable generated in this way without an exception being thrown.

Comment: You can enumerate it as many times as you want, Resharper generates a warning because in many cases it can be bad for performance (if the IEnumerable is the result of a complex Linq query for instance, because then re-enumerating means re-executing the query. It's better to cache the results in a collection)

Answer (score 2):

This does lead to multiple enumerations of *an* enumerable.

If I change your code to this:

```
private static void MultipleEnumerations(IEnumerable<int> nums)
{
    var otherNums = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var filtered = otherNums.Where(num =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}?", num);
        return nums.Contains(num);
    });
    foreach (var num in filtered)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<int> GetNums()
{
    Console.WriteLine("4!");
    yield return 4;
    Console.WriteLine("2!");
    yield return 2;
}
```

...then I can get the following output:

```
1?
4!
2!
2?
4!
2!
2
3?
4!
2!
4?
4!
4
5?
4!
2!
```

You can see that for each `otherNums` being tested it is running through `nums` (which is `GetNums`) each time. When testing `4` it only takes the first number of `nums`, but otherwise it is iterating it fully 5 times.

If you're wondering why `.Where` and the `foreach` **both** don't iterate thru the `otherNums` it is because `.Where` is run with a deferred execution model - it's only when you do a `foreach` or something like `.ToList()` that it executes.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper probably suggested changing the type of the parameter to `IEnumerable`, because there is no caller who would pass other type than (derived from) `IEnumerable`, Resharper suggested the simplest type.

`ICollection` adds only a few properties and methods to `IEnumerable` from which it derives, most importantly the `Count` property.

According to [this table](http://c-sharp-snippets.blogspot.cz/2010/03/runtime-complexity-of-net-generic.html), the `GetEnumerator()` method has the same complexity for most classes implementing `ICollection`.